# Angular2 - return observable of object instance

Tags: angular, observable

I have a piece of code that looks like this:

```
public getData(getFromServer: boolean) {
    return getFromServer
        ? this.http.get('url').map(res => res.json())
        : Observable.of(new MyObject());
```

If getFromServer is set, i want to return the json from the server. If it is false, I want to simply return a new instance of MyObject() to save the trip to the server. I thought this would work - but I am getting cannot .subscribe on undefined error...Thanks!

The caller function looks like this:

```
this.service.getData(getFromServer).subscribe(myObject => {
    this.myObject = myObject;
});
```

Comment: Post all the relevant code.

Comment: Added the caller code...

Comment: Can you narrow down which branch is producing the error? `getFromServer = true` or `getFromServer = false`? Both? From first glance (types, method signatures) - everything looks OK. Problem at runtime importing services?